# In C++11, dow can I reference an enum class defined inside a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums

Here is a simplified version of the code I am trying to write:

```
template<typename Derived>
class StateMachine
{
public:
  void SetState(Derived::State s) {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->TransitionTo(s);
  }
};

class MyFSM : public StateMachine<MyFSM>
{
public:
  enum class State {
    State1,
    State2,
    State3
  };
  void TransitionTo(State s) {
    _state = s;
  }
private:
  State _state = State::State1;  
};
```

I'm using c++11 with clang. The error I get here is `10:17: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'Derived::State'` for the declaration of `SetState`. I've also tried adding `typename Derived::State DerivedState;` and then using `DerivedState` instead of `Derived::State`, but then I get `error: unknown type name 'DerivedState'`.

More confusing still, I tried `typedef typename Derived::State DerivedState;` and then I get the error: `error: no type named 'State' in 'MyFSM'`. my last try was `typedef enum class Derived::State DerivedState;` and then I get the most confusing error of all: `error: no enum named 'State' in 'MyFSM'`.

I'm out of my depth with templates here and would welcome any help understanding this! Also, there may be a better pattern to use here. The main thing I'm going for is that the `StateMachine` class has some common functionality and then there are a bunch of different state machines, each with their own state and transition function. I have another way of doing it that requires passing in `this` to `SetState` (when called from within `MyFSM`, which is a simplified version of what I'm doing), but that's ugly for it's own reason. I'd love to avoid this tempalted class thing, but my main goal is making the derived classes as easy to write and understand as possible.

Comment: You seem to be confusing `typename` and  `typedef`.

Comment: @n.m, that's not the problem. The problem is that `Derived::State` cannot be found without a complete definition of `Derived`.

Comment: @n.m., without the complete definition of `Derived`, `typename Derived::State` can be found.

Comment: @RSahu I was addressing the first compilation error. The typename keyword is required in this situation. It makes little sense to talk about other problems before fixing the first one.

Comment: @n.m., the OP tried the `typename` route and wasn't sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may delay the type deduction by making `SetState` a template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Derived>
class StateMachine
{
public:
  template <typename State>
  void SetState(State s) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<State, typename Derived::State>::value, "Not a derived state");
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->TransitionTo(s);
  }
};

class MyFSM : public StateMachine<MyFSM>
{
public:
  enum class State {
    State1,
    State2,
    State3
  };
  void TransitionTo(State s) {
    _state = s;
  }
private:
  State _state = State::State1;
};

int main() {
    MyFSM fsm;
    fsm.SetState(MyFSM::State::State1);
    // error: static assertion failed: Not a derived state
    // fsm.SetState(0);
}
```

Comment: Excellent yes, It can infer the `State` type and the `is_same` call verifies that you are doing something sane. Thanks!

Comment: Works nicely as default template parameter too: `template <typename State = typename Derived::State>`

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
void SetState(typename Derived::State s) {
```

does not work since the complete definition of `Derived` is not known at that time.

You can use a slightly refactored code base to accomplish what you are trying.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename Derived, typename DerivedState>
class StateMachine
{
   public:
      void SetState(typename DerivedState::State s) {
         static_cast<Derived*>(this)->TransitionTo(s);
      }
};

class MyFSMState
{
   public:
      enum class State {
         State1,
         State2,
         State3
      };
};

class MyFSM : public MyFSMState, public StateMachine<MyFSM, MyFSMState>
{
   public:
      void TransitionTo(State s) {
         _state = s;
      }
   private:
      State _state = State::State1;  
};

int main()
{
   MyFSM v;
   v.TransitionTo(MyFSM::State::State2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler gets to `public StateMachine<MyFSM>` in `class MyFSM : public StateMachine<MyFSM>` it tries to stamp out `StateMachine<MyFSM>`.  When it does that `MyFSM::State`(`Derived::State`) has not yet been seen.  Since the compiler does not know about that type it issues the error.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, the problem is Derived is not full known when the CRTP Base is instantiated.

One option therefore is to defer the determination of the type you're interested in like this:

```
template<typename Derived, typename = void>
struct DeferredState
{
  using type = typename Derived::State;
};

template <typename Derived>
class StateMachine
{
public:
  template<typename T = void>
  void SetState(typename DeferredState<Derived, T>::type s)
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->TransitionTo(s);
  }
};
```

Since you *could* specialize the `DeferredState` template, the compiler has no option but to wait until you actually call `SetState` before determining the argument type. At that time, Derived is fully defined. And your problem is gone.